# Call react component's function from external JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying called the react component's function from a javascript function. On the initial stage, I want to call my function which is declared in react component but rather than a call from react I need to call it from a javascript function.

I know how to call a javascript function from react function. like below

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(){
    alert('Function from index.html');
  }
</script>
```

**React**

```
componentWillMount() {
  window.test();
}
```

But in my case, I want a totally reverse process, need to call react function from a javascript due to certain plugin initialization.

I went through other related topics but don't get an exact answer. so how should I do this?

Comment: window.fn = function(){} in react, then call it in js if exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can can assign a function to the **`window`** object as a function and call that from your script. So essentially you would do the following:

```
componentWillMount() {
  window.reactFunction = () => {
    console.log('Test');
  }
}
```

Then call it from your script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(){
    window.reactFunction()
  }
</script>
```

Admittedly I have no idea how exactly you plan to use this but this could be one way of accomplishing what you want by utilizing the global **`window`** object. The second part would realistically need some way of determining whether the react component has mounted (in a non trivial example), or just check for the existence of the method before calling it.

Comment: Thank you for reply let me try it.

Comment: actually i have functionality of HTML5 audio control with customized operation so react is not supporting or handle event so i must need to use javascript code to handle events so for that i need to call javascript to react function and react to javascript function. visa versa...

Comment: @ankitkanojia in case my answer doesn't cover what you need exactly, consider updating the original post with more details on your exact use case

Comment: no need for direction to my exact requirement of customization, I already settled up everything, the only thing I want is just called react component's function from a javascript function. so I think its probably feasible information to share for this POST.